# How to plot square corners of spatial object?

Tags: r, plot, spatial

Some data:

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)

pts1 = cbind(seq(50,850,100), 50)
pts2 = cbind(seq(50,850,100), 150)
df = data.frame(1:18)
ptss <- rbind(pts1,pts2)
Spts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(ptss, df)
sPts.B <- gBuffer(Spts, byid=TRUE, width=48, capStyle="SQUARE")
plot(sPts.B)
```

The result is what I´m looking for, a kind of grid.
Plotting `sPts.B` with `lwd=4` leads to squares with round corners, but I´d like to receive square corners. using the plotting parameter `lend` just produces one square corner.

How to make all corners square?

Comment: thanks for the hint. I edited the question.

Comment: They also appear rounded using `ggplot2`: `ggplot(data = fortify(sPts.B), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = "white", color = "black")`